# Problem with size image?

Tags: book, ebook

I planning to publish a children book "As a book & ebook" with images. I choose Landscape 9x7 for it. Now, I got some bad news that this will not fit ebook style. My image size is 2700*2100 pixel. Now, I looking for the best solution for my case. What should I do ?

Comment: Could you clarify what image size limitations you have for the ebook?

Comment: I don't know much about ebook sizes. In my case I think 1028*800 is the minimum. Is this good ?

Comment: Ok, so that's fine, your resolution is higher. I still don't know the exact problem. Will the e-book be in portrait? And your landscape photo doesn't fit then?

Comment: So, what is the best size image for ebook ?

Comment: I am sure there is a way to solve this, but I don't know yet which one. I think this can only be answered by seeing the picture and planned e-book layout. Possible options if the layout is fixed are cropping of the picture or scaling (or changing dpi). Here is a small guide on image sizes, does this help: http://pub.ink/ebook-images/ ?

Comment: Thank you for this article. I will do resize the image. No other option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best e-book formatting process?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/3395/best-e-book-formatting-process)